# Collection in Symfony 2 only get last item

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to fill a collection with information from user, but the list is coming only to the last item.

The collection is embed collection of form of Capitulo in a Libro. 
The LibroType is:

```
class LibroType extends AbstractType {

private $edita;

public function __construct($edita) {
    $this->edita = $edita;
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('titulo', 'text', array("label" => "Titulo: ", "required" => true, "attr" => array('class' => 'form-control')))
            ->add('anio', 'integer', array("label" => "Año: ", "required" => true, "attr" => array('class' => 'form-control')))
            ->add('numeroPaginas', 'integer', array("label" => "Páginas: ", "required" => true, "attr" => array('min' => 1, 'class' => 'form-control'),'precision' => 0, 'constraints' => array(
                    new Regex(array(
                        'pattern' => '/^[0-9]\d*$/',
                        'message' => 'Use solo números positivos.'
                    )))))
            ->add('esPmbok', 'choice', array('choices' => array(1 => 'Sí', 0 => 'No'), 'label' => '¿Es Pmbok? ',  'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => true, 'data' => $this->edita))
            ->add('idiomas', 'entity', array('class' => 'UciBaseDatosBundle:Idiomas', 'required' => true))
            ->add('pmbok', new PmbokType(),array('required' => false))
            ->add('capitulos', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new CapituloType(),
                'by_reference' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'label' => FALSE))
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Uci\Bundle\BaseDatosBundle\Entity\Libro'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName() {
    return 'uci_bundle_basedatosbundle_libro';
}
```

}

Part of  the VistaLibro:registrarLibro.html.twig:

```
  <!-- /Tabla capitulos -->

                            <table class="table demo table-bordered" id="tablaCapitulos" data-filter="#filter" 
                                   data-prototype="
                                   {% filter escape %}
                                       {{ include('UciAdministradorBundle:VistaLibro:prototipoCapitulo.html.twig', { 'form': form.capitulos.vars.prototype|e }) }}
                                   {% endfilter %}">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th data-hide="phone">
                                            Numero 
                                        </th>
                                        <th data-hide="phone">
                                            Nombre
                                        </th>
                                        <th data-sort-ignore="true" data-hide="phone" data-name="Acciones"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                                <a href="#" id="capitulo_link">Añadir capítulo</a>
                            <!-- /Acaba el contenido de capitulo-->
```

And the prototipoCapitulo.html.twig that is called in the table.

```
<td class="cols-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-3">
    {{ form_widget(form.numeroCapitulo) }}
</td>
<td>
    {{ form_widget(form.nombreCapitulo) }}
</td>
```

the action method:

```
public function aRegistrarLibroAction(Request $request) {
    $entity = new Libro();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(new LibroType(0), $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $error = '';
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $error = $form->getErrors();
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
            try {

                $em->persist($entity);
                $this->guardarCapitulos($em, $entity);
                if ($entity->getEsPmbok() == 1) {
                    $this->guardarPmbok($em, $entity);
                }
                $em->flush();
                $em->commit();
                return $this->redirectToRoute('uci_administrador_indicelibro');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $em->getConnection()->rollback();
                $error = $e;
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->render('UciAdministradorBundle:VistaLibro:registrarLibro.html.twig', array(
                'entity' => $entity,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'error' => $error,
    ));
}
```

And the js used:

```
function addCapitulo() {
        var collectionHolder = $('#tablaCapitulos');
        var prototype = collectionHolder.attr('data-prototype');
        var form = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, collectionHolder.children().length); //importante
        var removeFormA = $('<td href="#" onclick="addTagFormDeleteLink(event, this); "><span class="navigationSpace glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color: red; font-size:180%" ></span></td>');
        var newTr = $('<tr></tr>');
        newTr.append(form);
        newTr.append(removeFormA);
        collectionHolder.append(newTr);
        return prototype;
    }

    function addTagFormDeleteLink(e, elemento) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var removeFormA = elemento.parentNode;
        removeFormA.remove();
    }

        $('#capitulo_link').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            addCapitulo();

        });
```

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: The problem could be in your javascript. When you call addCapitulo() more than once I would check that collectionHolder.children().length is giving you an updated value when you add new elements. If it's not then you'll just be overwriting the same element multiple times when you post. Check that your post data has correctly incremented indexes for capitulos

Comment: Thank you Richard you was right, I was overwriting and the index did'n increment.

Comment: No prob, happy to help.